# Click thumbnail, change main image - NextGen or somethign else?

Tags: gallery, thumbnails, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I'm trying to get the main image to change depending on the thumbnail image clicked. I would want the main image to take its new src from the a tag of the thumbnail that was clicked.

Good example is [Gallery in 4 Lines](http://workshop.rs/demo/gallery-in-4-lines/) but I'm looking for some kind of an existing solution (plugin) for Wordpress. Not sure if NextGen can do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NextGEN Pro Horizontal Filmstrip Gallery display with caption option will display basically the same output as what you are referring to in the other example.